# Get current path when in a symbolic linked directory

Tags: ruby, symlink, pwd

When I am in a symbolic liked directory (`ln -s ...`) and invoke Ruby's `Dir.pwd` it returns the path of the target directory. I need a way to return the link directory like Linux's `pwd` do. The following script exemplify my need:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u
set -e

rm -rf '/tmp/root_dir'
mkdir -p '/tmp/root_dir'

mkdir '/tmp/root_dir/target_dir'
ln -s '/tmp/root_dir/target_dir' '/tmp/root_dir/symlink_dir'

echo "== Printing Linux PWD =="
(cd '/tmp/root_dir/symlink_dir'; pwd)

echo "== Printing Ruby version =="
ruby --version

echo "== Printing IRB version =="
irb --version

echo "== Printing Ruby PWD =="
(cd '/tmp/root_dir/symlink_dir'; echo  'puts ::Dir.pwd' | irb --noecho --noverbose)

echo "=== Running command \"pwd\" in Ruby ==="
(cd '/tmp/root_dir/symlink_dir'; echo  'system("pwd")' | irb --noecho --noverbose)
```

Output:

```
/tmp/root_dir/symlink_dir
== Printing Ruby version ==
ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [x86_64-linux]
== Printing IRB version ==
irb 1.2.6 (2020-09-14)
== Printing Ruby PWD ==
/tmp/root_dir/target_dir
=== Running command "pwd" in Ruby ===
/tmp/root_dir/target_dir
```

How can I get the symbolic link path as the current path instead of target path using Ruby?

---

Edit 1: added result for `system('pwd')` executed in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

I went with:

```
ENV['PWD'] || ::Dir.pwd
```

I got no other way to get the link directory in Linux than getting the value of environment variable `PWD`. When is not present (Other plataforms?) it uses the default way to get current directory in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Do you think using `system('pwd')` would be sufficient?

It definitely will give you the result you are after. But it looks like a hackish solution for me!

Comment: Did you try it? It doesn't work too. It will show target directory, not symlink

Comment: I tested, added the result in the question text: it returns the target link.